# Want to listen incoming call and out going calls

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I want to listen incoming calls and outgoing calls and this process should run as service.I made a activity which is working fine to recognize incoming and outgoing calls but I need to change it to service so that it can run into background.I can't find out how to change it.My activity follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
    {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        switch (state)
        {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //CALL_STATE_IDLE;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_IDLE", 10000).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", 10000).show();
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            //CALL_STATE_RINGING
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CALL_STATE_RINGING", 10000).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

  }
}
```

**And my Second question** can I install a service without an activity into my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `extends` `Service` instead of `Activity`. You do need an activity to start a service. You can start your service at boot by register a `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` and have your `broadcast receiver` start your service. However, from `ICS` upward you need an activity to launch your service at least once. After that the activity will never be needed again.

Comment: **from ICS upward you need an activity to launch your service**

If I am going to start this service using ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED then? I don't want to use any activity.

Comment: For ICS and up you need to launch a service from an activity once for boot completed to call your receiver. I guess this is for security reason.

Comment: another thing if I am going to make this activity to service where should I put this 

`TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mTelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);`

Comment: in onCreate of the service

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an intent to start a service. You can create an activity that only starts your service, and this activity does not have a view.
Make your class extend `Service` rather than `Activity`, and create another activity that instantiates your service and executes `startService(yourserviceInstance);`